# How is $\Delta_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ related to $\Delta_{\mathbb{S}^n}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I am reading the following preprint https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.08203.pdf where in eqn (1.6) the authors say that solving
$$-\Delta_g v + \frac{n(n-2)}{4}v = \frac{n-2}{n-1}Rv^{2^*-1}$$
is the same as solving
$$-\Delta u = R(F(x))u^{2^*-1}$$
where $(\mathbb{S}^n,g)$ is the sphere with the usual metric, $2^*=\frac{2n}{n-2}$, $v:\mathbb{S}^n\to (0,\infty)$ and $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to (0,\infty)$ and takes the form
$$u(x) = \left(\frac{2}{1+|x|^2}\right)^{(n-2)/2}v(F(x))$$
where $F(x)=\left(\frac{2x}{1+|x|^2},\frac{|x|^2-1}{1+|x|^2}\right)$ is the inverse stereographic projection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{S}^n$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}.$

I tried to establish this relation by computing
$$\Delta u=\left(\frac{2}{1+|x|^2}\right)^{(n-2)/2}\Delta v(F(x))+v(F(x))\Delta\left(\frac{2}{1+|x|^2}\right)^{(n-2)/2}+2\nabla \left(\frac{2}{1+|x|^2}\right)^{(n-2)/2} \cdot \nabla v(F(x))$$
but I am not sure how to compute $\Delta_{\mathbb{R}^n} v(F(x))$ (that is converting it into $\Delta_{g} v(F(x))$) and $\nabla v(F(x))$
in $\mathbb{R}^n$.